# When monitoring routing changes with rtnetlink, how can you get a new routes metric?

Tags: c, linux

I've found a couple of examples for listening to `RTNETLINK` events, both directly from the kernel and using `libmnl`. The `libmnl` example does exactly what I want in that it listens for route changes and reports them. The example is complete and can be found here:

https://github.com/threatstack/libmnl/blob/master/examples/rtnl/rtnl-route-event.c

It seems to have code to support printing out the metric of a route on line 54:

```
    if (tb[RTA_METRICS]) {
    int i;
    struct nlattr *tbx[RTAX_MAX+1] = {};

    mnl_attr_parse_nested(tb[RTA_METRICS], data_attr_cb2, tbx);

    for (i=0; i<RTAX_MAX; i++) {
        if (tbx[i]) {
            printf("metrics[%d]=%u ",
                i, mnl_attr_get_u32(tbx[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

However although the example application prints out a lot of information, the metric (even if explicitly set at creation time) isn't shown. If I use `ip route replace` and change the metric, it will show the same information as previously, but again the metric is missing.

Is it possible to get the route metric in this way?

Is there a better approach to get routing table updates that include the route's metric?

**Update**

`ip monitor` does show the metric changes so they are seemingly available, just not being returned to the test application (null pointer in `tb[RTA_METRICS]`.

Answer (score 2):

After checking the source code for `ip monitor` and looking at how Strongswan does it for MOBIKE I discovered that the kernel doesn't use `RTA_METRICS` to report the metric, it uses `RTA_PRIORITY`. From the Strongswan mailing list (https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2017-September/011501.html):

> If a system uses routing metrics, we should honor them when doing (manual)
>   routing lookups for IKE. When enumerating routes, the kernel reports priorities
>   with the RTA_PRIORITY attribute, not RTA_METRICS. We prefer routes with a
>   lower priority value, and fall back to longest prefix match priorities if
>   the priority value is equal.

With regard to how this could be done with the `libmnl` example, the code snippet looks like this:

```
        if (tb[RTA_PRIORITY]) {
            printf("metric=%u ", mnl_attr_get_u32(tb[RTA_PRIORITY]));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, the nomenclature is rather bewildering in this case.